# Difference between sort by a specified column and sortMode="multiple" in Primefaces Datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces-3.5 and JSF.

I am fetching a `List of Cars` on based on some criteria(Color, Brand and etc.) and a click of a `button` and displaying it in a DataTable.

I need to sort a DataTable based on a `Column(Car Id)` in the DataTable, so i had used the below code.

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtSortView.cars1}" style="margin-bottom:40px" sortBy="#{car.id}" sortOrder="ascending">
            <f:facet name="header">
                Sort By a Specified Column
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{car.id}">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Which sorts the DataTable by default with ascending order of Car Id,
but if i change the criteria and then get the list then the DataTable
is in descending order of Car Id!.

If i use `sortMode="multiple"` then i am unable to use `sortBy` and `sortOrder`.

I know there is a difference exists between `Sort by a specified Column and sortMode="multiple"`, but i want to understand it much more clear way.

**Sample Code:**

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtSortView.cars1}" style="margin-bottom:40px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Single Column Sort
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{car.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtSortView.cars2}" sortMode="multiple">
        <f:facet name="header">
            Multiple Column Sort with Metakey
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Id" sortBy="#{car.id}">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

[DataTable Sorting ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml)

[Suggested as a Duplicate] ([Initial sortorder for Primeface datatable with multisort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199805/initial-sortorder-for-primeface-datatable-with-multisort)), but my question much talks about the difference between `Sort by a specified column and SortMode`.

Comment: This can all be found in the PrimeFaces documentation

Comment: "*If I use `sortMode="multiple"` then I am unable to use `sortBy` and `sortOrder`*". How? The statement is untrue except `sortOrder` is something which is wonky till date - at lease until PrimeFaces 5.1 final (community release). "*I know there is a difference exists between `sort` and `sortMode="multiple"`*". There no such an attribute like `sort`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initial sortorder for Primeface datatable with multisort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199805/initial-sortorder-for-primeface-datatable-with-multisort)

Comment: @Tiny Thanks for the comment. I tried the combination of sortBy and sortOrder with sortMode="multiple" which have produced a error. I will check that once again and i will come back.

Comment: I cannot comment anything about `sortOrder` just because it did not work for me in my attempts and I did not even consider it an issue because it is quite easy to set a default order of our interest anyway. On the other hand, I have been using `sortMode="multiple"` and `sortBy` everywhere since the beginning at several places and found no problem with them except for some ignorance in the library itself in the beginning.