# primefaces datatable multiple sort with specified name on id

Tags: sorting, datatable

I want to have multiple sort on datatable. I find below link that seems more match on my case. [Initial sortorder for Primeface datatable with multisort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199805/initial-sortorder-for-primeface-datatable-with-multisort) 
But I have one field that have specified sorting. I have only three different values. e.g. TCS(first in sorting), School-input (second), self-input (third). Their sorting are not on letters as you see. How to handle this?? Do you have any suggestions to help me??

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by adding one more parameter in the class of typeId which will be sorting. typeId is hardcoded assigned to different type string.